# In Java, during Object#equals() call, do both objects necessarily have same hashCode ? Do we need to ever compare hashCode within equals()?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have read somewhere, in context of HashMap :
`hashCode() allows sorting objects by their hash values, and then the Object#equals method only needs to be invoked when objects share the same hash value.`

Does it mean that when eventually equals() method is called , then hashCode was already compared and found to be necessarily equal? Is there any exception for this scenario?

2nd part of question: Will it ever make sense to check hashCode() of both objects in equals() method ?

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(obj instanceof InternalObjectSerialized)) {
            return false;
        }
        InternalObjectSerialized<?> inputObj = (InternalObjectSerialized<?>) obj;

        if (!(Arrays.equals(this.bytes, inputObj.bytes))) {
            return false;
        }

        // Does the following line make any sense ??
        return this.hashCode() == inputObj.hashCode();
    }
```

Comment: "then hashCode was already compared" - by who? It's really not clear what code you're talking about. If you mean in HashMap, then yes, I'd expect it to have checked the hash code already. But I'd recommend reading the contract on java.lang.Object for what equals/hashCode implementations *must* abide by.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes Sorry I mean in context of hashmap.

Comment: we cannot see what exactly `hashCode` is doing, neither how the corresponding object is declared, so we cannot say if it makes *any* sense (at least it is very dubious... also because different instances can still return the same hash code)

Comment: When you override `equals` you do not need to compare hashcodes within equals — what you _do_ need to do is **also** override `hashCode` and _make sure_ that two objects that are .equals to each other _generate_ the same hash code. -- Always override hashCode when you override equals.

Comment: *Does it mean that when eventually equals() method is called , then hashCode was already compared ...* Probably, but it’s not guaranteed. Exceptions, I neither know nor care. *Will it ever make sense to check hashCode() of both objects in equals() method ?* Hardly. I can’t think of a situation where it would. Remember that calculating the two hash codes will nearly always take more time and more code lines than just comparing the relevant instance variables of the two objects.

Comment: Summary:  No, you should *never* make use of the hashCode in an equals method.  hashCodes are *not* guaranteed to be unique, by design.  But make sure any two objects which *are* equal, also return the same hashCode.

Comment: It is conceivable and plausible that hashCode comparison in `equals` might be used as an optimization to quickly detect that two values are not equal,  if computing the hash code is cheaper than testing equality (perhaps because the hash has been cached), but that's all.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Conceivable, indeed. Something like if both objects have cached hash codes and they differ, immediately return false (meaning not equal), otherwise compare field by field. Plausible? Not with me. And for use with `HashMap` seen isolated, probably pointless since, as the questioner suggests, the map has probably already checked the hash codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize from the comments:

> In Java, during Object#equals() call, do both objects necessarily have same hashCode?

Two objects that are `.equals` to each other do *need* to have the same hashCode, but it is up to you to write the *equals* method and the *hashCode* method to make sure this is true.

- Two objects can have the same hashCode and *not* be equal, because of [hash collisions](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision).
- Two objects that are equal *must* generate the same hashCode.

When a `HashMap` calls `equals()` on two key objects, has it first ensured that the hash codes are equal? Probably, but not guaranteed and it’s an implementation detail that we should not need to know about. Also the implementation of `HashMap` has changed more than once over the Java versions and may change again, so the answer may depend on Java version. You may inspect the source code of `HashMap` in your Java version to see.

The `HashMap` distributes the key-value pairs into so-called *buckets* based on the hash code of the key. In case of a *collision* — two or more pairs landing in the same bucket — it may conceivably compare keys belonging in the same bucket for equality. Since there are many more possible hash codes than there are buckets, this could mean also sometimes comparing objects with different hash codes using `equals()`.

Other kinds of `Map` such as a `TreeMap` probably don't use hash codes at all.

> Do we need to ever compare hashCode within equals()?

No, you do not need to compare hashCodes in your implementation of `.equals`, in fact you should *not* do that.